# HTML slideshow isn't working as it should

Tags: html, slideshow

Im making a slideshow in HTML, and here is my code:

```js
var cur = 0;
var max = $('.slides div').length;

var $curSlide;

setInterval(function() {
  $($('.slides div')[cur]).fadeOut(500, function() {
     $($('.slides div')[cur%=max, ++cur]).fadeIn(500);
  });
 
}, 2000);
```

```css
.slides img {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.slides div:not(#first) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slides">
  <div id='first'><img src="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/lib/images/javascript-illustration.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg/1200px-HTML5_logo_and_wordmark.svg.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*OFsc0SD55jhi8cjo7aCA4w.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

It works the first time but it won't repeat!!!
It runs through the slides once but can't run again.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, the [comma operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) Classical error.

 In the line:

```
$($('.slides div')[cur%=max, ++cur]).fadeIn(500);
```

You are getting the remainder first, then incrementing `cur`, whereas what you should be doing, is **increment first then get the remainder:**

```
$($('.slides div')[++cur, cur%=max]).fadeIn(500);
```

That should solve your problem, try it out!

Comment: Hmmm.. Let me see